# ClassNotFound Exception GlassFish Netbeans Library project

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, glassfish, classnotfoundexception

I have an entreprise application with an EJB and WAR project that have to use a library project (Model).

I've imported the library project in the library folder of both projects.
It seems to work until now, I do not know why but when I start the project I get a ClassNotFound Exception in Server Logs.

I'm using GlassFish Server and JSF Framework (Java Server Faces).

So this is the error I got in the server log :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type model.GameModel not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.<init>(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.of(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:193)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:80)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:175)
    ... 49 more

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.GameModel
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:833)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 78 more
```

- I already have tried to remove/re-import the library
- To check all the imports.
- To clean & build, run, deploy, restart the server, remove the server
  and add it again, etc.
- To start NetBeans as administrator.

But I've no idea what's going wrong here, if someone could give me clue I'll appreciate.

**Edit : I tried to add a package "model" inside both projects instead of calling my library, it's working but that's not how I want to implement my model.**

(Sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.GameModel`. Is `model.GameModel` your own class or from some dependent library?

Comment: model.GameModel is a class I created by myself in the library project I cretaed myself too.